# Regular expression: between brackets, starts with a specific string but do not ignore spaces

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract from a string all unique occurrences of a specific pattern. My string is
    `text = 'My name is {{user_name}} {{user_second name}}. I am {{anything_else}}'`
I want to extract the text inside the double brackets that start with "user_". For the given string I would like to have the following array
`["user_name", "user_second name"]`.
I am trying to achieve this using the following regular expression but in case there is a space inside the square brackets it ignores it somehow.
`text.scan(/\{{(customer_\w*)\}}/).uniq.flatten` returns `["user_name"]`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try [`/{{(user_[^}]*)}}/`](https://ideone.com/9CSMxz) or `/{{(user_.*?)}}/`

Comment: It works!!!!! Thank you very much. You should post it as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\w*` only matches 0 or more word chars and does not match whitespace.

It seems the best pattern for this scenario is a lazy dot pattern:

```
/{{(user_.*?)}}/
         ^^^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/4k0jp9eTIx) and an [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/9CSMxz).

The `.*?` here will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first `}}`.

If the user names cannot have `}`, you may use `/{{(user_[^}]*)}}/` regex, too. The `[^}]*` negated character class matches 0 or more chars other than `}` chars. There is another difference from `.*?` based solution: `[^}]` also matches line break chars. To make the `.` match line breaks, add a `/m` modifier with the first regex, `/{{(user_.*?)}}/m`.